# как добавить методы в HashMap (Phone Book

Tags: java, hashmap

Пишу программу Телефонная книга и не получаются следующие методы. HashMap у меня состоит из класса Юзер и сета Контактов (с номерами телефонов домашний, мобильный).

```
static Map<User,Set<Contact>> phoneBook = new HashMap<>();
    Contact firstContact = new Contact(532564856);
    Set<Contact> setOfContacts = new HashSet<>();
 ...
```

searchByName - метод должен делать поиск по имени

```
static void searchByName(String name) {
        if (phoneBook.containsKey(name))
            System.out.println(phoneBook.get(name));
        else{
            System.out.println("Sorry. The contact is not exist");
        }
    }
```

searchByNumber - метод должен делать поиск по мобильному/домашнему номеру телефона

```
static void searchByNumber(int num) {
    if (phoneBook.containsValue(num)) {
        System.out.println(phoneBook.get(num));
    }else
        System.out.println("Number is not found");
}
```

printAllContacts - метод должен выводить все контакты (имя - номер или номера)

```
static void printAllContacts(){
        System.out.println("ALL CONTACTS " + phoneBook);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

addNewContact  - добавить новый контакт

```
static void addNewContact(Set<Contact> addNewContact, Contact contact){      
        if (addNewContact.contains(contact)) {
            addNewContact.remove(contact);
        }
        addNewContact.add(contact);
    }
    static void deleteContact (String contactToDelete) {
        phoneBook.remove(contactToDelete);
        System.out.println("Deleted contact: "+contactToDelete);
    }
```

Comment: Для чего вам такая сложная конструкция, ы ведь не граф собираетесь чертить?

Comment: @Maksym Почему бы Вам просто не добавить `Set<Contact>` в `User`  в качестве поля?

Comment: думаю что буду позже писать gui для данной программы. Буду писать как первую для учебы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мапа у вас содержит ключ - user объект, значение - set

```
Map<User,Set<Contact>> phoneBook
```

А вы пытаетесь искать по `String`

```
static void searchByName(String name) {
        if (phoneBook.containsKey(name))
```

Можно ли среди людей найти строчку? Вряд ли.

---

Вам надо либо переделать `Map<User,Set<Contact>>`  на `Map<String, Integer>`, тогда ваши методы начнут работать.

Либо изменить методы на

```
searchByUser(User user);
searchBySetContect(Set<Contact>);
```

Либо последний вариант, который уберет всю полезность `HashMap`

```
static void searchByName(String name) {
      for(User user : phoneBook.keySet()){
        if (user.getName.equals(name))
        ...
```

---

И по поводу этого метода:

`addNewContact` - добавить новый контакт

```
static void addNewContact(Set<Contact> addNewContact, Contact contact){      
    if (addNewContact.contains(contact)) {
        addNewContact.remove(contact);
    }
    addNewContact.add(contact);
}
```

Set содержит только уникальные значения, т.е.

```
    if (addNewContact.contains(contact)) {
        addNewContact.remove(contact);
    }
```

ненужно, т.к. Set сам все сделает (Если в классе Contact переопределены методы equals и hashCode)

Comment: Изменил я  эти два метода searchByUser(User user);
searchBySetContect(Set<Contact>); , но теперь не могу понять как мне искать. Допустим в методе main я пишу searchByUser(); в него я должен передать какого то юзера, например firstUser, так? Но тогда у меня выводит что то типо [home number is 532564856
,  home number is 789278125, work number is 568214824
, home number is 456823127

Comment: Как мне определить какое конкретное имя и номер я хочу найти?

Comment: @MaksymSereda ну это уже от вашей задумки зависит, хотите найти "Вася" ищите Васю, "Петя" ищите Петю итд